# Quering Facebook notifications using Social framework in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework

I've looked around the Social Framework, but it's difficult to navigate. I figured out how to get the latest @mentions on twitter, which I do like so:

```
            NSURL *mentionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json"];
            NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [parameters setObject:@"3" forKey:@"count"];
            [parameters setObject:@"0" forKey:@"include_entities"];


                SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                   requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                             URL:mentionsURL
                                                                      parameters:parameters];
                [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



}];
```

I was wanting to adapt this to get the latest notifications from Facebook, but I'm unsure what to put in the URL and parameters to make this work.